# Does accessing a static member invoke the base class constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, garbage-collection, clr

Even though all common sense says no, I still am asking this question just to get a second opinion and become sure.

If I have a class hierarchy like so:

```
public class IntermediateObjectContext : System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
{
    public static Action<string> PrintHello { get; set; }
}

public class MyDatabaseContext : IntermediateObjectContext
{
    public ObjectSet<Foo> Foos
    {
      get { // ... }
    }
}
```

Then from a third, unrelated to Entity Framework object, if I access the static member of the IntermediateObjectContext class, in this case, if I subscribe to the delegate of the class, will that somehow instantiate a new ObjectContext?

```
class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
      IntermediateObjectContext.PrintHello += SayHello;
    }

    public void SayHello(string s)
    {
        Debug.Print(s);
    }
}
```

All reason says no, common sense says it won't, but I just want to make sure. I am trying to track down a memory hogger object.

**What happens if**

What happens to the memory situation if I have a static collection for SomeClass types like so:

```
public class SomeClassCollection
{
    private static Collection<SomeClass> _col = 
                new Collection<SomeClass>();

    public void Add(SomeClass c) { _col.Add(c); }

    public void Remove(SomeClass c) { _col.Remove(c); }
}
```

And then some code adds `SomeClass` instances to SomeClassCollection like so:

```
public SomeClassCollectionConfig
{
    public static RegisterSomeClasses()
    {
        SomeClassCollection.Add(new SomeClass());

        SomeClassCollection.Add(new DerivesClassOfSomeClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) No, it won't instantiate an object.

(2) What happens if:

There it will allocate the empty collection `col` the first time any member of `SomeClassCollection` is accessed.

From the code, that's all it will do. You aren't using `_col` anywhere in the code presented.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me clarify the question. I forgot to add the bit that I am indeed adding `SomeClass` type instances to the _col. I just left it because I thought it was obvious.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Ok, so (2) will be the same (forgot to mention that calling the class constructor counts as a member of the class being accessed).

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewWatson. My biggest worry is: will any of this inadvertantly instantiate an object context, because my database has over 1,200 tables with some tables having more than 4 million records. It appears that it won't but I just wanted to confirm because something wrong is happening in the code that is using a lot of memory.